# Send keyboard event using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have two python scripts. First one is just a script waiting for user keyboard input. When user presses a key it prints a pressed key value.

Second script calls first one through subprocess using Popen like this

```
p = Popen('python first_script.py', shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
print p.communicate(input="some value paased through")[0]
```

I got it working when I send through string values. But I don't know how to send keyboard event and how to read it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess` per se has no facilities to "send keyboard events" (to the sub-process or to any other process).  You need other aproaches, such as the one [this article](http://kvance.livejournal.com/985732.html) shows for Windows.

Comment: Is it possible for AppActivate to be executed in the background. So application is not focused visualy?