# how to pass 'F' key events etc to python subprocess

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send keyboard event using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531953/send-keyboard-event-using-subprocess)

I'm trying to control a program in DOS using the python subprocess module. How do I pass keyboard actions/events (e.g. F1,...,F12, Alt, Alt-Shift etc) to the program? e.g.

```
proc=Popen(['my_program','keyboard actions'],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,shell=True)
```

Comment: [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) maybe?