# Python 3 failing to send message to C# subprocess

Tags: c#, python, subprocess

Fairly new to python and currently using Python 3.5.2. I have a subprocess where I need to monitor the output, process it and display it via kivy. This works fine.

But there comes a point where the subprocess needs a reply to continue or exit. This is where I am utterly stuck.

```
chimp_cmd = 'sudo /usr/bin/mono ' + os.getcwd() + '/aDotNet.exe ' + aVeryLongListofParam    # aVeryLongListofParam is read from a file
child = subprocess.Popen([chimp_cmd], 
                                        shell=True, 
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        bufsize=0) # no difference with bufsize set to 1
 # while loop that reads in the data    

     # do funky stuff with the output data, (this works and relies on a lot of starts with comparisons)

     if ( (b''.join(MyOutputLineList).decode("utf-8) ).startswith("Would you like"):

         # wait for the thread that gets the response - this works

         if usrReply = UsrKeyReply.no:
             print("received user no")        # we get to here 
             # attempts at sending a reply:
             ret_value = child.stdin.write(b'n\n') # this doesn't work for me
             print(ret_value)
             print("test1") 
             os.system('pidof mono')        # for debug

         elif usrReply = UsrKeyReply.yes:
             print("received user yes")  # also get to this point 
             stdout, stderr = child.communicate(input=b'n\n')[0]
             # child.stdin.flush()  <-- this hangs the code
             print("test2")                 # doesn't work for me either
```

Other details. 
On Ubuntu.
The python scirpt is invoked with:

```
sudo python3 myscript.py
```

Yes it needs to be sudo because mono needs access to a USB port.

DotNet.exe is third party

DotNet.exe works fine if invoked directly from the command line.

I know that the message does not get back to the subprocess because apart from nothing happens, I can open another terminal and monitor the child with:

```
sudo strace -p <mono's PID>
```

Here I can see the exe going through the motions and playing nicely with the python script, and I see the prompt "Would you like..."

When the python script reaches the point of sending back the reply the child doesn't terminate (when 'n') or continue (when 'y')

Help!

As suggested by @Hermann I have tried changing to:

```
bufsize=1,
universal_newlines=True)
```

also amended the reply to

```
stdout, stderr = child.communicate(input='n\n')[0]
child.stdin.flush()
```

The script hangs after this.

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can flush the write buffer explicitly by calling `child.stdin.flush()`.

Alternatively, you can try adding `bufsize=1` and `universal_newlines=True` in your `subprocess.Popen` call for switching line-buffered mode. Note that the behaviour varies wildly accross Python 3 versions as mentioned in the various comments in [subprocess stdin buffer not flushing on newline with bufsize=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571305/subprocess-stdin-buffer-not-flushing-on-newline-with-bufsize-1).

Comment: Thank you for the reply but, no joy with either of these suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, it turns out that python does indeed send data to the subprocess. The problem lies with how the input is handled on the C# side.

```
Console.ReadKey().Key /* this will not work with python subprocess piped stdin */
```

versus

```
piped_reply = Console.ReadLine() /* will work with python piped stdin */
```

See SO question: [C# Console receive input with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199528/c-sharp-console-receive-input-with-pipe)

Comment: It is not worded clearly, but https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/471w8d85.aspx suggests that Console.ReadKey() does not actually read from standard input, but rather waits for a key pressed event. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531953 suggests there is no platform independent way of sending keyboard events in python.

Comment: agreed, if the C# application is only looking for keyboard input then there isn't much you can do in python.